# Why is this JS not firing

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have this Markup, and the way this is supposed to work is the user click on the "icon arrow" and this following JS is supposed to fire which will display the hidden content, in other words opening the window. this works in another program, but is there any reason this is not firing.

Here is the markup:

```
   <div data-bind="foreach {data:movies}">
    <div class="content-item full bottom-border">
    <div class="content-item-container">
        <div class="movie-listing-header">
            <a class="icon arrow"></a>
            <div class="movie-details">
                <div class="title"><a href="#" data-bind="text: MovieName, attr: { href: DetailsUrl }"></a></div> 
                <div class="info">
                    <div>
                        <span class="rating" data-bind="css: 'rating-' + (MovieRating || 'NR').toLowerCase().replace(/-/, '')"></span> 
                    </div>                        
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="icon right-arrow"></a> 
</div>
        <div class="showtimes">    
              <div data-bind="template: { name: 'movie-grouped-showtimes-template', data: $data }"></div>    
        </div>    
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and here is the .js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon.arrow').click(function () {
        var active_el = $(this);
        $('.movie-listing-header').each(function () {
            if ($(this).get(0) === active_el.parent().get(0)) {

                if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
                } else {
                    $(this).siblings('.showtimes').show();
                }
                $(this).toggleClass('active');

            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('active');
                $(this).siblings('.showtimes').hide();
            }
        });

    });
});
```

Comment: could this be because of the data binding

Comment: Please give more context to what you're describing. What do you mean by "in other words opening the window"? No window was mentioned. Also, what do you mean by "this works in another program"? What program?

Comment: `$(this).get(0)` There's absolutely no reason to do that. Just use `this`.

Comment: And frankly, for your `active_el`, if all you need is to get its parent, then again, I'd not use jQuery. `var active_el = this;` ... `if (this === active_el.parentNode) {`

Comment: sorry, it is not a window, it is hidden content. It works in another program that does NOT use Knockout.js instead it builds the content using imbedded repeaters